# Writing classes having strings and vectors in binary files in c++

Tags: c++, string, class, vector, binaryfiles

```
class student
{
        string name;
        string rno;
        int dd,mm,yy;
        int nob;
        vector<string> buks;
}
```

Can I write this class in a binary file successfully?
Would presence of string or vector(having internal pointers) in the class cause any     problem in writing this class to binary file?

Comment: +1. Waiting for answer, because buks is just like a pointer, just wonder how we can store its value to binary file.

Comment: You have to serialize all the content, but that is possible and there are already libraries (such as `boost::serialization`) that can be used to support it.